# wxWidgets autoconf setup doesn't set include dirs as -Isystem but as -I

Tags: c++, autotools, autoconf, include-path

I have inherited a build system that uses autoconf and automake to build. I am not at all familiar with how this works except on a high level.

The build system itself works fine. However a lot of warnings are generated from system headers. In my case wxWidgets. The cause of this is that the include dir of wxWidgets is passed as -I instead of `-isystem`. I have searched online but I can't find how I can change this.

The following code is in the `configure.ac` file:

```
AM_OPTIONS_WXCONFIG
AM_PATH_WXCONFIG(3.0.2, wxWin=1, , ,[--debug=yes])
if test "$wxWin" != 1; then
    AC_MSG_ERROR([
                wxWidgets must be installed on your system
                but no wx-config script could be found.

                Please check that wx-config is in path, the directory
                where wxWidgets libraries are installed as returned by
                'wx-config --libs' is in the linker path (LD_LIBRARY_PATH
                or equivalent variable) and wxWidgets version is 2.9.4 or
                above.
        ])
    fi
if test "$wxWin" != 0; then
    AC_DEFINE(HAVE_WXWIDGETS,1,[define if the wxWidgets 3.0.2. or higher is available])
fi
```

Then there is a `Makefile.am` which does the following:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = project
project_SOURCES     =   {sources here}


project_CPPFLAGS    =   $(AM_CPPFLAGS) $(PROJECT_CPPFLAGS) $(WX_CPPFLAGS)

project_CFLAGS      =   $(AM_CFLAGS)   $(PROJECT_CFLAGS)    $(WX_CFLAGS)

project_CXXFLAGS    =   $(AM_CXXFLAGS) $(PROJECT_CXXFLAGS) $(WX_CXXFLAGS)

project_LDFLAGS         =   $(AM_LDFLAGS)

project_LDADD       =   $(AM_LIBADD)   $(WX_LIBS)
```

There doesn't seem an option that I can specify it as a system header in some way.

Do anyone of you know how I can tackle this?

Comment: Did you mean "-isystem" (with lowercase 'i')?  That one is provided by GCC, at least, though its use is uncommon.

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes -isystem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with autoconf. It's the `wx-config` tool that is the culprit. That tool is used to obtain the include directories. For instance invoking `wx-config --cxxflag` will result in this:

```
-I/usr/lib/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-3.1 -I/usr/include/wx-3.1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ -pthread
```

Which is passed to the compiler. There are a couple of ways of solving this. Either manually replace it in the output or patch wx-config.

Comment: You should consider looking into the specific warnings that are generated when the default options are used.  Your wxWidgets installation is flawed either way, but it's not clear that the flaw is in `wx-config`, as opposed to reflecting *bona fide* flaws in the headers themselves, missing or incorrect dependencies, *etc*..

Comment: @JohnBollinger These are warnings not errors. A lot of them due to the flag `-Wconversion`. Not sure how my installation is flawed since the headers actually contains the code that is warned about. It seems more that wx-config is flawed that it actually informs the compiler that the wx headers are part of the project which is not the case.

Comment: I think the idea is that if the compiler is warning about problems from these headers, perhaps the headers themselves are actually buggy.  Using `-isystem` suppresses the warnings, but that doesn't necessarily mean that the resulting code will be correct.

Comment: @TomTromey It's not like I will now start maintaining wxwidgets. It's an external dependency. I don't really care if my external dependencies don't reach the quality gate for my own code.

Comment: @CryptoNoob, your installation is flawed either because the header elicits warnings from the compiler, or because `wx-config` (which is part of the installation) emits the wrong options.  That they are warnings as opposed to errors just means that the flaw(s) is less severe than others you can imagine.  That they are only warnings does *not* mean it is safe to ignore them without understanding their nature.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I'm not sure what you mean. It's obvious that a codebase that is decades old will pass `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion` in the most recent compiler without any issue. I mean compile any larger project and you will surely find warnings. I don't think my installation is flawed I think wxwidget simply has code that emits warnings with my compilation flags. I checked some headers and they match the remote source so that is not the issue. It seems to me that wxwidgets compilation just isn't as strict as my own.

See this paste for typical errors I get: https://pastebin.com/fZPp94yu

Comment: I don't understand why you're arguing this point, @CryptoNoob.  You're the one who posed the question in the first place.  That your wx installation exposes you to such issues *is* a flaw.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Then what should I do? I compiled wxwidgets from source. You are basically saying something which is completely unhelpfull. I don't think my installation flawed, and if you think it is then explain why it is flawed and how I can then install wxwidgets the good and proper way. because simply saying it's flawed because there are warnings in the header files with custom compile commands is not really a valid point.

Comment: It's a risk but whether it causes bugs depends on the particular warnings, etc.  Anyway I think this answer is a reasonable one and should be accepted; you can work around the problem in your configure script or Makefile by rewriting the appropriate WX_*FLAGS variable to use -isystem.